# Jekyll `_data/people.json` arrays: reforming and sorting

Tags: arrays, for-loop, split, jekyll, liquid

I'm working on a Jekyll project that has a file called `people.json` in the `_data` folder. The formatting of the JSON file is like so:

```
{
    "name" : "George Michael",
    "topics" : ["Egg", "Cousins"],
    "contact" : [
        {
            "email" : "name@web.com",
            "twitter" : "@name"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Tobias",
    "topics" : ["Analyst", "Therapist"],
    "contact" : [
        {
            "email" : "name@web.com",
            "twitter" : "@name"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is build a tag list, of sorts, using the `topics` information. I have tried:

```
{% for tag in site.data.people %}
<li>
    {{ tag.topics }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Which returns:

```
<li>EggCousins</li>
<li>AnalystTherapist</li>
```

Ideally, the markup I'd like returned would be:

```
<li>Analyst</li>
<li>Cousins</li>
<li>Egg</li>
<li>Therapist</li>
```

I've been trawling the Liquid docs, and I think I can loop through and break these into a new array with `split` and then apply a `sort`, but the way of actually doing this eludes me completely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your json is not valid. My jekyll seems to prefer :

```
[
    {
        "name" : "George Michael",
        "topics" : ["Egg", "Cousins"],
        "contact" : [
            {
                "email" : "name@web.com",
                "twitter" : "@name"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Tobias",
        "topics" : ["Analyst", "Therapist"],
        "contact" : [
            {
                "email" : "name@web.com",
                "twitter" : "@name"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Nevertheless, I find this solution quite good. Note that the first for loop is supposed to create a topics array with no duplicates.

```
{% comment %}Create an empty array for topics{% endcomment %}
{% assign topics = "" | split: "/" %}

{% for author in site.data.people %}
  {% for topic in author.topics %}

    {% comment %} As we don't want duplicates in our "topics" list we test it {% endcomment %}
    {% if topics contains topic %}
      {% comment %} Do nothing. Could have used unless, but I find if else more expressive. {% endcomment %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign topics = topics | push: topic %}
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Here you have a nice list which you can loop in : {{ topics | inspect }}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
{% for tag in site.data.people %}
   {% for item in tag %}
   <li>
      {{ item }}
   </li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```